# Wordpress. Mostrar mismos datos en dos páginas sin reteclearlos

Tags: base-de-datos, wordpress, variables, variables-globales

Tengo que mostrar en varias páginas los mismos datos, pero no quiero teclearlos varias veces por pesadez y porque puede dar lugar a que se modifiquen en un lado y se olvide en otro. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?¿Existen variables comunes que se puedan mostrar?¿Se puede crear una tabla propia y consultarla para mostrar los datos?

Gracias.

Comment: indícanos donde quieres ver el mismo dato ¿en todos los post? ¿en todas las paginas? ¿en todos los vídeos? ¿solo en algunos? si es en algunos, indícanos que criterio utilizaras para identificar estos post. Una vez definas ésto, se te podrá dar una respuesta indicando el archivo que necesitas modificar.

Comment: Yo hago esto a través de _hooks_. Son los conocidos `add_action` de WP. Colocas en la plantilla de ese tipo de posts una marca (hook) y añades una acción a través de PHP (`functions.php` o `custom.php`si usas un framework) el `add_action` llama a una función donde puedes preguntar por el id de los posts (en caso de que no todos los que tengan esa plantilla tengan que llevar ese contenido fijo, si todos lo deben llevar no preguntas nada), e introduces el contenido, desde el mismo PHP. Es una opción útil si no quieres estar creando plantillas para personalizadas casi idénticas.

Answer (score 0):

Es cuestión de crear un [Custom Post Type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) (CPT), donde se almacenan las informaciones cómunes y luego usar [Metaboxes](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/custom-meta-boxes/) y [Shortcodes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) para añadir esa información a la hora de escribir un post/página normal.

Tengo en WordPress Developers un ejemplo completo de cómo hacer eso: [Create custom [sourcecode] shortcode, the right way?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/116044/12615)

A la hora de escribir un post aparece este Metabox donde elijes el contenido CPT que quieres usar y te muestra el shortcode para añadir dentro del post. Sí cambias el contenido del CPT, todos los shortcodes mostrarán la información actualizada.

[image]